# Samsung Galaxy Tab doesn't play 3gp or mp4 with h.263, but plays mp4 with h.264/youtube

Tags: android, h.264, mp4, android-videoview, galaxy-tab

I'm trying to play some videos from web, using VideoView.setVideoPath()

This videos are .mp4's
Using MediaInfo, I found some important lines:

```
Codec (Human Name)................................MPEG-4 Visual
Codec Profile.....................................Simple@L1
Codec Settings (Matrix)...........................Default (H.263)
```

This videos don't play on Galaxy Tab, but play well on any HTC and other Samsung with Android.

I also tried to play a .3gp, but this also doesn't play on Galaxy Tab and plays on any other android smartphone.

The only video that I could make to play on Galaxy Tab are .mp4's from Youtube.

Can anyone recommend me how to make .mp4's with H.263 to play on Galaxy Tab without changing encoding?

And, maybe more important:
Does anyone knows any other possible Android devices on which this videos won't play?

**Update:** Maybe an important information: when I download the video and play it locally, with integrated browser, any of the above videos play well. The only problem is that GalaxyTab doesn't support even progressive video streaming of h.263/.3gp

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is weird because it should totally be supported: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core

Comment: I think that they removed the support for this video type to be progressively streamed. When I download the video locally, it plays well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transcode my videos to XviD which play nicely on my Galaxy Tab. They're just dvd rips for my kids to watch.

My understanding is that there's no H.263 codec available for the tab.